# PyDev and Android

Tags: android, python, eclipse, macos, pydev

I have a problem with importing a file called android.py and it is essential to the project I'm working on. Eclipse IDE gives me a warning saying "Unused Import". I don't know if it's because I haven't set an environment variable (which I don't know how to do, either), or if it is for an entirely different reason. If someone could respond ASAP, that would be nice because I'm on a deadline. THANKS SO MUCH!

PS: I am running on Mac OS X, NOT WINDOWS!

Comment: It just means that you are importing some module and not using it. Its pydev message, not pythons error or warning.

Comment: OK. I'm VERY NEW at eclipse and I don't know my navigation around the software. Thanks

Comment: In pydev you can control its messaged. For example to disable unused import messages you can do as shown [here](http://i.imgur.com/Hnpq7nY.png)